# Timer act crazy, Resets in different times not as defined

Tags: c#, timer

I have this class

```
public class ResetClock
{
    public delegate void ResetFunc();
    private ResetFunc m_ResetFunc;
    private event ResetFunc Reseted;

    private Timer m_Timer;
    public ResetClock(int second)
    {
        double r = second * 1000;
        m_Timer = new Timer(r);
        m_Timer.AutoReset = false;
        m_Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onTimerTick);
        Reset();
    }

    public void SetResetMethod(ResetFunc method)
    {
        m_ResetFunc = method;
    }

    public void Terminate()
    {
        m_Timer.Stop();
        m_Timer.Dispose();

        m_Timer = null;
    }

    private void onTimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_ResetFunc == null)
        {
            if (Reseted != null) Reseted();
        }
        else
        {
            m_ResetFunc();
        }

        Reset();
    }
    #region Public

    public void Reset()
    {
        m_Timer.Reset();
    }

    #endregion


}


internal static class  TimerEx{
    public static void Reset(this Timer timer){
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

My application is showing the reset page when this class reaches the seconds defined in the contractor. when a Reset() method calls, the Timer should reset the it self and begin the timer from 0.

for some reason after the application is running few days the reset event is firing after few seconds and not the number of seconds that i defined in the first application initialization

does anyone have any idea....??? I braking my head through the wall to find the answer..

Comment: how long does it take your "Reset Page" method to return?

Comment: what do you meanby return?

Comment: I mean: How long does it take your "Reset Page" to complete its operation?